# Storage Persistance in Codename one

Tags: android, ios, iphone, codenameone

I've started using the Storage class in codename one and am a bit confused. How persistant is this storage? When I reload my app in the simulator it appears to erase the storage. Will it be erased when the app is updated in the app store (ios or android) ?

Answer (score 0):

Storage is persisted and will remain between runs. In the simulator you can see it in the `.cn1` directory. I'm guessing you got an exception in the console due to the way you stored the data or used an invalid call/API usage when loading. Without code I'm just guessing.